# C++ segmentation fault I don't understand - recursive string function

Tags: c++, string, recursion, segmentation-fault

Ok the function ascii to binarys turns a char into a string of its binary representation

I'm attempting to first initialise the string "binarys" to Null if it is filled with junk with the call to "blanker".

then in "text to binary" I'm attempting a recursive function which uses the length of the string binarys as an iterator. the function should translate a string of chars into the binary representation of their ASCII values.

the first call of text to binary works fine, producing an 8 char string in "binarys".

the first Recursive call causes a seg fault. GDB says It cannot access the memory of the string "binarys" when it is passed to "blanker" in the first recursive call, I don't understand why ? I'm passing it a non-NULL string

```
void blanker(char messystring[])
{
  for (int count = 0; count < strlen(messystring); count ++)
    {
      if (messystring[count] != 0 and messystring[count] != 1)
    {
       messystring[count] = '\0';
    }


}


int text_to_binary(char str[], char binarys[])
{
  char converted[8];
  int count;
  if (binarys[0] != NULL)
    {
      blanker(binarys);
    }

  count = strlen(binarys) / 8; //serves as an iterator
  if(str[count] == '\0')
    {
      return -1;
    }
  ascii_to_binary(str[count], converted);
   strcat(binarys, converted);
  text_to_binary(str, binarys);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's hard to see how this will ever work. If `binarys` is filled with junk, how will `blanker()` know how long it is? How is `strlen()` going to work on a junk-filled, non-zero-terminated string?

Comment: If it *did* work, on the next call you'd set the first non-`0` or -`1` char (presumably `'0'` or `'1'` from `ascii_to_binary()`) to `0`, so `strlen()` will be `0` again.

Comment: Well initially "blanker" did not exist and was not called. binarys is passed in in main.cpp as a newly declared char array, and it was working fine.

Comment: But then binarys[] suddendly started becoming initialised with 6 chars of junk at the beginning

Comment: There is no garantee that a `char[]` is filled with zero.